# Azure API Management REST API User

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to invite users programmatic to azure API management developer portal. There are API to [create users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776330.aspx#CreateUser). Is there an API available for Invite user?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 3rd party mailing API like [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com) or [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com) to email an invite and include a link in the email to the sign up page of the developer portal.  Would that be sufficient?